# How much CMHC fee do I need to pay if I cannot put 20% down on a new home

Tags: canada, mortgage, home-insurance

I am trying to calculate how much CMHC fee I will need to pay if I can only put in 10% downpayment on a new home as opposed to 20%.

So as per this calculator:
[image]

It shows:8640.

My question is: is the amount 8640 the total premium over the 5 yr term of the mortgage, or is it the premium I pay for each of the first 5 years of the mortgage?
I assume that after five years, my total equity would become at least 20%, hence on the subsequent term I need not pay any CMHC fee.

Source:http://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/co/buho/buho_023.cfm

Comment: Hi Victor, can you slip in a link to the site the calculator came from?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the link that says _"See Table of Premiums (opens in a new window)"?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one time payment, usually just added to the mortgage.  You will have a mortgage of $400k +$8,640 - the $40k downpayment = $368,640.  The mortgage will be insured for the entire life of the mortgage regardless of the term you choose.

Comment: Or, as the image shows, it can be paid in a lump sum up front.